# What is known about finding heavy hitters in a sliding window?

Tags: ds.algorithms, streaming, streaming-algorithms, sliding-window

This question is strongly related to [another question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/22605/additive-error-in-counting-the-number-of-1s-in-a-sliding-window) I asked here a few weeks ago.

In this problem setting we have a stream of elements $s_1,s_2,...$, such that $\forall i: s_i\in \mathcal X$ for some set $\mathcal X$.

At time $t$ we get $s_t$, and required to update our data structure to be able to answer queries of the form *"did $x$ ($x\in \mathcal X$) appear at least $N\epsilon$ times in the last $N$ elements in the stream ($s_{t-N+1},s_{t-N+2},\dots ,s_{t}$)?"*.

**What is the best algorithm (memory-wise, and then runtime as a secondary objective) that answers these queries correctly w.p. 1?**

Two related papers, which implement a *sliding bloom filter* (answering queries of the form "did $x$ appear at least once in the last $N$ elements") appeared last year, [one by Naor and Yogev](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-45030-3_48) and [the other by Dautrich and Ravishankar](http://www.edbt.org/Proceedings/2013-Genova/papers/edbt/a23-dautrich.pdf).

These results can be seen as a special case of the sliding heavy hitters problem for $\epsilon=\frac{1}{N}$.

Comment: Just a thought: if you can get a sliding window version of the CM sketch (which is very related to the Bloom filter), then well-known reductions should give a heavy-hitters algorithm as well. I imagine some dyadic intervals trick could give a sliding window CM sketch.